# How to convert XML to CSV efficiently

Tags: php, xml, csv, memory

I’m testing my PHP code that converts XML to CSV .

I take from XML from a web site as the HTTP response by using  `HTTP_Request().`

However I need more than 15GB memory although XML size is 500MB.

I checked memory consumption each steps of processing XML to CSV like bellow.

`sendRequest()` 1.5MB to 500MB   <- data size of HTTP response is about 500MB too

`$res = getResponceBody()` 1.0GB

`$xmlstr = mv_convert_encoding($res)`  1.7GB

`$xml = sinplexml_load_string($xmlstr)` 600MB

`$json = json_encode($xml)`  1MB to 6.5GB

`$arry = json_decode($json, true)` 10.0GB

`Create CSV from $array` 4.5GB

I want know how to reduce memory consumption.

Are there some steps I can short cut for converting XML to CSV?

Especially `json_encode` and `json_decode` I’m not sure how they work but
If I can cut them I can reduce 90% of memory consumption.

Comment: Do you really need to load the entire document tree in memory? Could you please show a sample of the XML document?

Comment: Have you tried using PHP DOM? http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Sorry,I can't show you XML document but I'll tell you waht this XML is from whole oralce table and this XML's tag is from colmn_name of table.

Comment: You are creating and keeping multiple unecessary variables in your code. To honor their existance PHP don't drop them despite the fact you will never use them again. `unset()` variables you don't need anymore to make PHP drop them from memory.

Comment: I also don't get why you have JSON envolved. Just use `(array)$xml` to convert that object into an array or use `get_object_vars()` for the same purpose.

Comment: @Havenard: That is a common copy and paste mistake: there are some examples that suggest to convert the whole SimpleXMLElement into an array by json en- and then de-code it. These examples also suggest then it would be easier. Which is totally misleading. Best thing you can do here is to just throw that part out. The memory consumption alone here is a very good reason why :)

Comment: @Havenard: Casting to array is not really useful nor necessary either. SimpleXML is very fine to operate on, this keeps memory footprint low, too.

Comment: Yes, I was supposing he did that because `fputcsv()` takes array as parameter, I'm not sure what input he has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save memory, here is a way how you can do it:

- Open the HTTP URI in **XMLReader** with [`XMLReader::open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.open.php).
- Create an [**SplFileObject**](http://php.net/class.SplFileObject) for the CSV file.
- Iterate over the XML via the **XMLReader** and adding line by line to the CSV file via [`SplFileObject::fputcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fputcsv.php).
- After the iteration tell the CSV file object to flush write buffers via [`SplFileObject::fflush`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fflush.php).

Shameless self plug: One library to make iterating over the XML easier for **XMLReader** is [hakre/XMLReaderIterator](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator), you can find some examples already here on Stackoverflow.

The benefit of this methodology is that you do not need to load the whole XML document at once. You also do not need to convert the whole structure into an array (which actually would not even be necessary in your case, as **SimpleXMLElement** could have been used directly by you to write to the CSV file, however you would still need to create the **SimpleXMLElement** (600 MB).

If the XMLReader seems too complicated, just remove the `json_encode` / `json_decode` part from your script and create the CSV from `$xml` (**SimpleXMLElement**) directly. Forget `$json` and forget `$array` you don't need these. [The basic usage examples form SimpleXML](http://www.php.net//manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) should show you how you can traverse and iterate your `$xml` directly. If the XML becomes really too large for memory, you can switch to **XMLReader**.

Comment: I tried `SplFileObject::fflush` but error message  `Call to undefined method SplFileObject::fputcsv()`was shown. It may be included in `PHP` form `5.4.0` .My `PHP` is `5.3.14`.I have to find another way to covert XML to CSV without `json_encode / json_decode `

Comment: I changed my code to create CSV from SimpleXMLElement with looping and editing each row instead of using `SplFileObject`  Now memory consumption has been reduced. But looping process took long time. I’ll ask this problem as another thread.

Comment: Yes ask another question and yes, looping for the memory save is normally a trade with time, it takes longer then but it does scale better with memory needs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown much of your code but from what you have shown it seems like you are using json_encode and json_decode to convert a string into a single element array. This is highly inefficient. If this is the case then just remove these lines

```
$json = json_encode($str);
$arry = json_decode($json,true);
```

and replace them with

```
$arry = array($str);
```

Also, it should not take 4.5GB to convert an array to CSV. Use php's built in functions for this. Do something like this

```
$fp = fopen('output.csv','w'); // at start of script output process
```

then when you have an array to output do this

```
fputcsv($fp, $arry);
```

and remember to close your handle when you are done with the file

```
fclose($fp);
```

Another way to save memory is to use unset to free up left over variables from your read-in process. 
Example, after $res = getResponceBody() and $xmlstr = mb_convert_encoding($res) you should be able to call

```
unset($res);
```

Since mb_convert_encoding creates a copy of the original string with the new encoding. The original string shouldn't be needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to convert XML to CSV:

1. Install Sumo & Python
2. Clone the whole sumo solution from this [link](https://github.com/argos-research/sumo/blob/master/tools/xml/xml2csv.py)
3. After you clone the solution, run the `xml2csv.py` file with the following command to get the CSV file:

   ```
   python xml2csv.py ../../../abc.xml
   ```

   We use `../../../`    because as per my directory, `abc.xml` is above three root folders with respect to `xml2csv.py`.

Comment: Maybe it is worthwhile to mention that this is not a general xml2csv converter but is tailored to sumo outputs. While it is quite general, it will ignore all character data and just parse the elements and the attributes.